# Parse error syntax error unexpected if T_IF

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I don't understand why i'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) on this if statement. I know that you will get this error if you forget a ; but I didn't. Could someone see anything that I have missed? Thank you!!

```
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if (count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";﻿
            if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {   <-- This is line that is throwing the error
                return $this;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want I can put my whole db.class.php up here but I don't see a reason to. Just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I pasted the code into PhpStorm I can see an extra character on the end of `$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";`

I remove that character and everything checks out. When I paste that character in here it's invisible. Try deleting some characters before and after, then type them back in.

Comment: That's Weird, I knew that I didn't see anything. Thank you for that!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a U+FEFF at the end of the line before your if block.  Removed it and it works

Comment: Why does this not show up in my text editor, but I opened it in another and it was there. I'm using sublime text 2